# How to change the opacity of chosen scatter plot points

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to create an interactive scatter plot so the user can select points with the cursor, so the chosen points are highlighted and the rest are faded.
Right now it only works if the color is changed, how can i change the opacity and keep the original colors?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class SelectFromCollection(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, collection,c, alpha_other=0.3):
    self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
    self.collection = collection
    self.alpha_other = alpha_other

    self.xys = collection.get_offsets()
    self.Npts = len(self.xys)
    self.c = c

    # Ensure that we have separate colors for each object
    self.fc = collection.get_facecolors()
    if len(self.fc) == 0:
        raise ValueError('Collection must have a facecolor')
    elif len(self.fc) == 1:
        self.fc = np.tile(self.fc, (self.Npts, 1))
    self.lasso = LassoSelector(ax, onselect=self.onselect)
    self.ind = []

def onselect(self, verts):
    path = Path(verts)
    self.ind = np.nonzero(path.contains_points(self.xys))[0]
    self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other
    self.fc[self.ind, -1] = 1
    self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
    self.canvas.draw_idle()

def disconnect(self):
    self.lasso.disconnect_events()
    self.fc[:, -1] = 1
    self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
    self.canvas.draw_idle()


np.random.seed(1)
x, y, c = rand(3, 100)
subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), autoscale_on=False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw)
pts = ax.scatter(x, y,c=c, s=100)
selector = SelectFromCollection(ax, pts, c)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I used the method self.collection.get_facecolors(), to get the format and values, then I just changed the value of the 3rd column for the chosen indices like this:

```
fc = self.collection.get_facecolors()
fc[self.ind, 3] = 1
fc[others, 3] = self.alpha_other
self.collection.set_facecolors(fc)
```

cheers